# Azure pipeline : SqlAzureDacpacDeployment fails to execute

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines

My pipeline is stuck on deployment job with message `The agent request is not running because all potential agents are running other requests. Current position in queue: 1`

This message is wrong. If I remove the SqlAzureDacpacDeployment task below and if I only keep the simple echo command, it will execute just fine. So the problem has something to do with the SQL task. Only there is no log and I can't figure out what's wrong.

I have triple checked all parameters and they are correct. I run the build on a dedicated VM and I have added the VM IP Address to the Firewall rules of SQL Server.

What else can I do to troubleshoot this problem  ?

```
- script: 
    echo "hello"

- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: 'Azure SQL InlineSqlTask'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'mysubscription id'
    ServerName: my-server.database.windows.net
    DatabaseName: mydb
    SqlUsername: admin
    SqlPassword: my password
    deployType: sqlTask 
    SqlFile: $(workFolder)/Scripts.sql
```

Comment: To confirm, if you do nothing after you get the "the agent request is not running..." message, does it hang forever? Also do you get the same behavior if you eliminate the - script step?

Comment: yes it hangs forever. And yes I get the same behavior if I remove the -script step. If I remove the SQL task however it works just fine and it displays "hello" before finishing.

Comment: If you run with s self-hosted agent  , you can try to [update your self-hosted agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv5Dn.png) to the latest version to see if it works.

Comment: I have upated the self-hosted agent to to the latest version. It doesn't change anything. I'm struggling with this as there is absolutely no log information.  Is there any way to get more feedback from the pipeline (some debug info perhaps ?)

Comment: I gave up... I am using a powershell script to execute sql instead of this task. If anyone knows how to make the task work, feel free to post an answer, but in the end I think using my own script is much easier and it works at least.

Comment: It might be that your agent is missing a capability required to run the SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1 task. This causes your agent not to pick up the build